# Delphi treeview multiselect drag and drop gives index out of bounds error

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, treeview, multi-select

I have a TTreeview with nodes that may be designated as a folder or file.
MultiSelect is true.  MultiSelectStyle contains msControlSelect and msShiftSelect.

If I select a non-contiguous number of nodes then drag & drop on a folder, I get an index out of bounds error.

```
procedure TRoleFrame.tvViewsDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
var
  Src, Dst: TTreeNode;
  LDestIsFolder: boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  inherited;
  Dst := tvViews.GetNodeAt(X,Y);  // Dst must be assigned due to DragOver below
  LDestIsFolder := Dst.ClassType = TInfoNodeFolder;

  for i := 0 to tvViews.SelectionCount-1 do begin
    Src := tvViews.Selections[i];

    if LDestIsFolder then
      Src.MoveTo(Dst, naAddChild)   //  Add a file to a folder
    else
      Src.MoveTo(Dst, naInsert);
  end;

  FDirty := true;
end;

procedure TRoleFrame.tvViewsDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer; State: TDragState;
  var Accept: Boolean);
var
  Src, Dst: TTreeNode;
begin
  inherited;
  Src := tvViews.Selected;
  Dst := tvViews.GetNodeAt(X,Y);
  Accept := Assigned(Dst) and Assigned(Src) and (Src <> Dst);
end;
```

The error occurs in the DragDrop event.

```
for i := 0 to tvViews.SelectionCount-1 do begin
```

When the for loop starts, SelectCount is correct.  The count = actual number of nodes selected.  Eg 5.

After the 1st MoveTo occurs, SelectionCount is always 1 (meaning Selections[0] is the only valid node)

In the next iteration of the loop i=1.  Selections[1] is out of bounds.

So it appears that all bets are off with regards to SelectionCount and Selections once one of the selected nodes have been moved.

My question is, what is the correct approach to implement multi-select drag & drop?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate.  I don't get an A/V in COMCTL32.DLL or anywhere else.

I get a Delphi "Index out of bounds" error.  And I can see exactly why it's happening.

For loop begins with SelectionCount = 5

After 1st iteration of the loop, SelectionCount = 1.  

I'm guessing (not 100% sure) that the MoveTo operation is clobbering the Selctions array.

Comment: But the answer to the linked question is exactly what you need to do to fix your problem. Read the whole answer to understand why.

Comment: Did you read the linked duplicate (and it's  answer) before deciding they're not the same thing? I don't think you did. :-) Read the first code sample and the paragraph that immediately follows it. I see a `TTreeNode.MoveTo` in the code you've posted, which means that the duplicate question is indeed relevant.

Comment: Oops!  I'm terribly sorry. My bad :)
I did indeed stop reading when I got to the A/V in COMCTL32.DLL